# Change color for toggle button based on active/inactive status (Bootstrap4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, togglebutton

Very new to HTML etc, and I would like to have a series of BS4 buttons that can be activated (stay activated until user clicks/deactivates them). I would furthermore like to have the button background change color when activated or not.

[Sample buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0As7.png)

I have seen a number of similar question on here, but I haven't gotten anything to work. My current "solution" is to make a new button, btn-sample, and put it in a CSS code file which is referenced after my BS4. Somehow its not working, however.

Here is my btn-sample code:

```
.btn-sample { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #b7b7b7; 
  border-color: #130269; 
} 

.btn-sample:hover, 
.btn-sample:focus, 
.btn-sample:active, 
.btn-sample.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-sample { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #2196F3; 
  border-color: #130269; 
} 

.btn-sample:active, 
.btn-sample.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-sample { 
  background-image: none; 
} 

.btn-sample.disabled, 
.btn-sample[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample, 
.btn-sample.disabled:hover, 
.btn-sample[disabled]:hover, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample:hover, 
.btn-sample.disabled:focus, 
.btn-sample[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample:focus, 
.btn-sample.disabled:active, 
.btn-sample[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample:active, 
.btn-sample.disabled.active, 
.btn-sample[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample.active { 
  background-color: #b7b7b7; 
  border-color: #130269; 
} 

.btn-sample .badge { 
  color: #b7b7b7; 
  background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Again, I just tacked it into a CSS file and referenced that file. I'm not sure if there needs to be any prefix there or not.

My HTML code is the following:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <span><button class="btn btn-sample active", value = >Sample Button</button></span>
```

The issue is I just want this to happen with this one button, I don't want to change the whole class b/c I use the buttons elsewhere and I don't want them to change. So even if the solution is some in-div HTML line, that would work as well.

I would really appreciate any help, especially if it could be implemented from scratch, with the correct style references etc at the top.

Very much appreciated.